Defining function with rotated domain
In this paper, they define a smooth and periodic function:
$$
f: [-\pi, \pi) \to \mathbb{R}
$$
and then consider its rotation by angles $\alpha \in [-\pi, \pi)$, which they write as
$$
f_\alpha(t) = f(t-\alpha ~\text{mod} 2\pi).
$$
I'm a bit confused by this definition. If $t= \pi$ and $\alpha = -\pi/2$, then
$$
t-\alpha ~\text{mod} 2\pi = \pi + (\pi/2) \text{mod} 2\pi = \pi + \pi/2 = 3\pi/2,
$$
for which $f$ is undefined. Am I misunderstanding the notation here? or perhaps I am misunderstanding what it means to `rotate the domain' of a function?

If $t=\pi$ and $\alpha=-\frac\pi2$ then
$$t-\alpha\text{ mod }2\pi=\pi+\frac\pi2\text{ mod }2\pi=\frac32\pi\text{ mod }2\pi=^\blacktriangle\left(\frac32\pi-2\pi\right)\text{ mod }2\pi=-\frac\pi2\text{ mod }2\pi$$
Infact $\blacktriangle$ is justified by the definition of the congruence relation:
$$a=b\quad(\text{mod }2\pi)\:\Longleftrightarrow\:2\pi\:|\:a-b$$
So
$$\frac32\pi=-\frac\pi2\quad(\text{mod }2\pi)$$ because $2\pi$ divides
$\frac32\pi-\left(-\frac\pi2\right)=2\pi$. Lastly you have:
$$f_{-\pi/2}(\pi)=f\left(\pi+\frac\pi2\text{ mod }2\pi\right)=f\left(-\frac\pi2\right)$$
